# Query regarding Facebook oauth for mobile apps and website

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

I'm building a website and a mobile app to go with it which uses facebook oauth for user log in, but I have a doubt. I would like to use the same Facebook App ID on both platforms, however I'm not certain as to how to go about it because from my limited knowledge of the Facebook SDK, the Oauth for websites relies on the redirect url, which becomes a problem for the mobile app.

If anyone has any experience with building a website and a mobile app using Facebook Oauth, can you please share your insights and what is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly use the same APP_ID.
In the settings page for your application you can set up may different urls that are all connected to your application as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]
You can see here the ability to give different urls for any of the given types of interaction

- Website - (eg. for facebook connect)
- Page Tab - for applications with in facebook pages
- App on facebook - the classic canvas application
- Mobile web - Generic mobile ready facebook application. (not specifically android or iOS)
- Native iOS App - iphone application
- Native android app - android application.

Hope this helps!